# Bloom filter probability for 16 bit integers

Tags: math, memory, probability, bloom-filter

I hava a list of 16 bit unsigned integers.

The only thing I want to know if a number is in the list.

I could use a bit vector for this. I just set bit[i] if i is in the list. To know if a number y is in the list i would look up bit[y]. This would be always give correct answer.

But I would like to save memory. And use less bits but allow false positives. I.e a number would be allow to return that it is in the list even though it is not. But no false negatives.

From my understanding bloom filter would achieve that.
What I do not understand is that when I use a bloom filter calculator the probability by setting for example:

- 400 entries (n)
- 400 bits (m)
- 1 hash function (k)

The probability for false positives is not zero. For example at https://hur.st/bloomfilter/

If I for example  on average have 400 different 16 bit numbers and want to use as little space as possible would a bloom filter be a good idea?

How should one think about the probabilty?
Clearly a bit vector gives perfect result with 16k bits. How much less space can I use with bloom filter and at which cost in in increased falsed positives.

Is there something better that could solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A Bloom Filter is likely the right object for what you need. The space requirements are what are at issue:

- you must have enough elements to make it reasonable (worth storing the hash function generators, at least), and
- enough bits to reduce the false positives to an acceptable level.

In other words, don’t focus on using as *little* space as possible; rather focus on using *enough* space. You will still be using less space than anything short of a custom, specialized filter.

Comment: My focus is though as little space as possible. The usage here HW where and now SW. And thinking more I do not see the advantage of bloom filter compare to just do something like dictionary[hash_elem&0xFFF] = 1 for every element in case I want to use 16 bits hash.